# Cómo le doy las funciones de editar y eliminar a mi crud?

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema al intentar darle funcionamiento al boton de editar y eliminar usuarios en mi tabla , esta extrae los datos de una base de datos mysql , no hay manera de que pueda agregarles estas funciones ya he intentado varias variantes pero nada espero que me puedan ayudar , aqui les dejo mi Código

Este es el codigo de mi tabla

```
<section id="table" style="padding: 6px 0 35px; margin-top: 20px;">
  <div class="container  text-center"></div>
  <div class="row g-4 justify-content-center mt-5" style="margin-top: 550px; ;">

    <div class="col-auto">
      <label for="num_registros" class="col-form-label">Mostrar: </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <select id="num_registros" name="num_registros" class="form-select">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <label for="num_registros" class="col-form-label">Registros </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto"></div>

    <div class="col-auto" style="width: 57pxpx;">
      <label for="campo" class="col-form-label">Buscar: </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-auto">
      <input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" class="form-control" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Realice su búsqueda ingresando cualquier parámetro ">
    </div>

    <div class=" col-auto pe-0">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-plus-fill" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
          <path d="M720-400v-120H600v-80h120v-120h80v120h120v80H800v120h-80Zm-360-80q-66 0-113-47t-47-113q0-66 47-113t113-47q66 0 113 47t47 113q0 66-47 113t-113 47ZM40-160v-112q0-34 17.5-62.5T104-378q62-31 126-46.5T360-440q66 0 130 15.5T616-378q29 15 46.5 43.5T680-272v112H40Zm80-80h480v-32q0-11-5.5-20T580-306q-54-27-109-40.5T360-360q-56 0-111 13.5T140-306q-9 5-14.5 14t-5.5 20v32Zm240-320q33 0 56.5-23.5T440-640q0-33-23.5-56.5T360-720q-33 0-56.5 23.5T280-640q0 33 23.5 56.5T360-560Zm0-80Zm0 400Z" />
        </svg>

        Agregar Usuario
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="col-auto me-sm pe-0">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editaModal">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
          <path d="M240-120q-45 0-89-22t-71-58q26 0 53-20.5t27-59.5q0-50 35-85t85-35q50 0 85 35t35 85q0 66-47 113t-113 47Zm0-80q33 0 56.5-23.5T320-280q0-17-11.5-28.5T280-320q-17 0-28.5 11.5T240-280q0 23-5.5 42T220-202q5 2 10 2h10Zm230-160L360-470l358-358q11-11 27.5-11.5T774-828l54 54q12 12 12 28t-12 28L470-360Zm-190 80Z" />
        </svg>
        Editar
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class=" col-auto">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eliminarModal">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 -960 960 960" width="24">
          <path d="M280-120q-33 0-56.5-23.5T200-200v-520h-40v-80h200v-40h240v40h200v80h-40v520q0 33-23.5 56.5T680-120H280Zm400-600H280v520h400v-520ZM360-280h80v-360h-80v360Zm160 0h80v-360h-80v360ZM280-720v520-520Z" />
        </svg>
        Eliminar
      </button>

      -->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">
              Agregar usuario
            </h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">



            <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->


            <form action="procesar_formulario.php" method="post" id="my-form">
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="nombre" class="form-label mt-3 mb-0">Nombre y Apellidos</label>
                <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre y apellido" require>
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label for="ueb" class="form-label mt-1 mb-0 ">UEB</label>
                  <select id="ueb" name="ueb" class="form-select" require>
                    <option value="">Elija una UEB</option>
                    <option>Dirección General</option>
                    <option>Dirección Técnica</option>
                    <option>Dirección Comercial </option>
                    <option>Dirección C.Humano </option>
                    <option>Dirección Económica</option>
                    <option>UEB AT&C</option>
                    <option>UEB Softur</option>
                    <option>UEB Datos</option>
                    <option>UEB Logística</option>
                    <option>UEB Varadero</option>
                    <option>UEB CienFuegos</option>
                    <option>UEB Villa Clara</option>
                    <option>UEB Ciego de Ávila</option>
                    <option>UEB Camagüey</option>
                    <option>UEB Holguín</option>
                    <option>UEB Santiago de Cuba</option>
                  </select>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="telefono" class="form-label mt-3 mb-0">Teléfono</label>
                  <input type="number" name="telefono" class="form-control" id="telefono" placeholder="Ingresar Número Telefónico" require>
                </div>


                <div class="col-auto mt-3">
                  <button type="submit" id="miBoton" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill" style="margin-right: 6px;" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                      <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.5 4.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3h-3a.5.5 0 0 0 0 1h3v3a.5.5 0 0 0 1 0v-3h3a.5.5 0 0 0 0-1h-3v-3z" />
                    </svg>Agregar
                  </button>

                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>

          <!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-sm d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table  table-striped table-bordered  table-hover  " style="width: 950px; text-align:center;">
        <thead>
          <tr class="border border-5">
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
            <th scope="col">UEB</th>
            <th scope="col">Teléfono</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="content">

        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
      <label id="lbl-total"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 " id="nav-paginacion"></div>
  </div>

</section>
<!-- Fin Seccion de busqueda-->
```

Este es el archivo donde realizo la consulta a la base de datos , muestro los datos y realizo el paginado de la tabla , yo quisiera darle el funcionamiento a los botones sin tener que cargarme todo eso

```
    <?php

require  '../ConexionBD/config.php';

$columns = ['id', 'nombre', 'ueb',   'telefono'];
$table = "campos";
$id = ' id';

$campo = isset($_POST['campo']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['campo']) : null;

$where = '';

if ($campo != null) {
   $where = "WHERE (";

   $cont = count($columns);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $cont; $i++) {
      $where .= $columns[$i] . " LIKE '%" . $campo . "%' OR ";
   }
   $where = substr_replace($where, "", -3);
   $where .= ")";
}

// limit
$limit = isset($_POST['registros']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['registros']) : 10;
$pagina = isset($_POST['pagina']) ? $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['pagina']) : 0;

if (!$pagina) {
   $inicio = 0;
   $pagina = 1;
} else {
   $inicio = ($pagina - 1) * $limit;
}

$sLimit = "LIMIT $inicio , $limit";

//consulta
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS " . implode(", ", $columns) . " 
   FROM $table
   $where 
   $sLimit";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
$num_rows = $resultado->num_rows;


// consulta para total de registros filtrados 
$sqlFiltro = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
$resFiltro = $conn->query($sqlFiltro);
$row_filtro = $resFiltro->fetch_array();
$totalFiltro = $row_filtro[0];


// consulta para total de registros filtrados 
$sqlTotal = "SELECT count($id) FROM $table ";
$resTotal = $conn->query($sqlTotal);
$row_total = $resTotal->fetch_array();
$totalRegistros = $row_total[0];

// Mostrar resultados
$output = [];
$output['totalRegistros'] = $totalRegistros;
$output['totalFiltro'] = $totalFiltro;
$output['data'] = '';
$output['paginacion'] = '';


if ($num_rows > 0) {
   while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
      $output['data'] .= '<tr>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['nombre'] . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['ueb'] . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= '<td>' . $row['telefono'] . '</td>';
      $output['data'] .= 
      '<td>
      <a href="?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary me-3" data-bs- 
      toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editar">Edit</a>

      <a href="?id=' . $row['id'] . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-bs- 
      toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#eliminar">Delete</a>
      </td>';
      $output['data'] .= '</tr>';
   }
} else {
   $output['data'] .= '<tr>';
   $output['data'] .= '<td colspan="4">Sin resultado</td>';
   $output['data'] .= '</tr>';
}


if ($output['totalRegistros'] > 0) {
   $totalPaginas = ceil($output['totalRegistros'] / $limit);

   $output['paginacion']  .= '<nav>';
   $output['paginacion']  .= '<ul class="pagination">';

   $numeroInicio = 1;
   if (($pagina - 4) > 1) {
      $numeroInicio = $pagina - 4;
   }
   $numeroFin = $numeroInicio + 9;
   if ($numeroFin > $totalPaginas) {
      $numeroFin = $totalPaginas;
   }


   for ($i = $numeroInicio; $i <= $numeroFin; $i++) {
      if ($pagina == $i) {
         $output['paginacion'] .= '<li class ="page_item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">'  . $i . '</a></li>';
      } else {
         $output['paginacion'] .= '<li class ="page_item"><a class="page-link" href="#" onclick="getData('  . $i . ' )">'  . $i . '</a></li>';
      }
   }


   $output['paginacion']  .= '</ul>';
   $output['paginacion']  .= '</nav>';
}

echo json_encode($output, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente? Para un CRUD, tendrías que determinar qué botón fue presionado y en base a eso ejecutar la acción de ese botón. Si se presionó el botón `Borrar`, ejecutar un `DELETE`, si se presionó `Actualizar`, ejecutar un `UPDATE`, etc.